# Why can't I access controller method by url?

Tags: codeigniter-4

Edited Question :
Hi, I am new to ci4 but understand some basic php and html. Currently I am watching some ci4 tutorial and while trying to copy what the tutor do I stumble upon some problem that I can't figure out. In the tutorial the tutor said that we can access the controller's method by url, but when I try it I got error.
so here is what i did :

- Downloading ci4
- extract and move the folder to htdocs
- start xampp
- start php serve stark
- set up .env

  CI_ENVIRONMENT = development

  app.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/'
- open http://localhost:8080/ in browser --> success

here is my app/Config/Routes.php :

```
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
```

here is my app/Controllers/Home.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        // return view('welcome_message');
        echo "Codeigniter 4 Introduction";
    }

}
```

In the tutorial, the tutor said and show that when accessing http://localhost:8080/Home/Index and http://localhost:8080/public/index.php  it the same as accessing http://localhost:8080/. The tutor did it but when I try it I got error as shown by picture below :

[can't access index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQnQi.png)

[can't access controller's method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyTq3.png)

Comment: What URL? What Controller?  What method?  Do you have a route set up?  There is nothing here anyone can help you with, please edit the question and add details.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I see several problems: 1) `$routes->get('/', 'Home::Index');` - you have an upper-case `I`, but your method is lower case: `public function index()`.  That means you've defined a route to a method which does not exist, which would logically give you a 404.  2) That route is for `/`, not `public/index.php`, and not `home/index`.  `/` means `http://localhost:8080`.  You have no routes for the URLs you are trying, so logically they would give you 404s.

Comment: Depending on your exact CI version and configuration, `http://localhost:8080/home/index` (with an lower-case `i` will work, because that maps directly to an existing controller and method name.  If you have `setAutoRoute()` disabled, that won't work.  See the docs about that for more info:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#use-defined-routes-only

Comment: Lastly if you have `public` appearing in your URL in the browser, you have something misconfigured - you definitely do not want that in production as it likely exposes sensitive data and code to the public internet.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Problem you mentioned.
1. Sorry for the typo, it was lower case in my code.
2. yes, that route is for the root.
3. I use the latest CI version.
4. Thank you, I read the docs but somehow missed the `setAutoRoute()` and missed it in the  `Routes.php` because it was commented.
I have set it to true and finally able to do as I want it.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial is using old version of the CodeIgniter4.
You are using the latest version.

Since v4.2.0, Auto-Routing has been disabled by default.
Because it is easy to create vulnerable apps where controller filters or CSRF protection are bypassed.